# Is there a way in Shopware to get SMTP host address inside of custom plugin?

Tags: shopware

I need value from the field "Shop settings > Mailers > Mail host". Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Seems your concept is wrong - why do you need the host? You should use the Mailer-Service to send an email.

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch config data like:

```
Shopware()->Config()->get('MailerHost')
```

Any parameters can be used as camelCase?

Database:       ->      Shopware

```
underscore_case ->      camelCase
```